# TideSDK - Problems trying to toggle a file chooser from a button

Tags: jquery, html, tidesdk, filechooser

I'm facing this problem: I wanna toggle a file chooser from a button.
On jsfiddle I can completely do that, while the same code doesn't work in TideSDK. This is really weird, and I'm going to think that this is a TideSDK related problem.

Link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7bA3/68/

Here the code:

HTML5

```
<input type="file" id="fileChooser" />
<button id="btnChoose">Browse</button>
<input type="text" id="fileChooserText" placeholder="Choose a file" />
```

CSS3

```
#fileChooser {
    position: relative;
    top: 350px;
    display: none;
}

#btnChoose {
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    left: -60px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

#fileChooserText {
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    left: -65px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 215px;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-indent: 5px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnChoose").click(function() {
    $("#fileChooser").click();
 });

    $("#fileChooser").change(function() {
        $('#fileChooserText').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

How can I get this working on tideSDK? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used TideSDK, but I am familiar with similar HTML/Javascript cross-platform development tools.  Once you start using one of these frameworks, you need to use the syntax of the platform.  So in the case of TideSDK, it looks like you need to use these options to open a file chooser dialog:

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.UI.UserWindow-method-openFileChooserDialog

You're writing code using Javascript, but you need to use the tools and libraries provided by the platform in order for it work.

I wish I knew more about the platform, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it really helped me a lot.
I was thinking that, infact, my approach, in this case, was totally wrong. For sure it will help even for future issues.